# How fix strange syntax problem when using execute function?

Tags: mysql-connector

I met an error when trying to use a function called execute to use one database. The information shows me that's about syntax, but I don't think so.
The following is my critical code and important information about the error.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'u' at line 1

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/


#include<string>

#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <mysql_driver.h>

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

int main()
{

    try {
  sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver driver;
  cout<<" driver "<<endl;
  sql::Connection *con = NULL;
  cout<<" con"<<endl;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  cout<<" stmt"<<endl;
  sql::ResultSet *res;
  cout<<" res"<<endl;
  /* Create a connection */
  //driver = sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::MySQL_Driver();

  SQLString ip_port("localhost:3306");
  cout<<"some debug string"<<endl;
  SQLString user("debian-sys-maint");
  SQLString password("fTlykRye1LwttC8f");
  con = driver.connect(ip_port, user, password);
  assert(con!=NULL);
  cout<<" root"<<endl;
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */

  SQLString schema("account");

  //con->setSchema(schema); 
  cout<<" table"<<endl;
  stmt = con->createStatement();
  cout<<" table*2"<<endl;
  assert(stmt!=NULL);
  SQLString db("use account");
  stmt->execute(db);
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * from user");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("name") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString("password") << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line "<<endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
  cout<<"\n";

}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I was confused that why the information was not about the sentence "use account". Instead, it was about "u". Thanks very much.

Comment: If this is an SQL problem it would be best to reproduce it directly in the MySQL client, the remove all the C++ from the question as it is not really a C++ question surely.

Answer (score 0):

[`USER` is a reserved word/keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-U).

You should [delimit your field names with backticks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) to avoid problems:

```
SELECT * FROM `user`
```

Comment: Em... I  want to execute "use account" and account is name of database. It seems that only the first letter "u" was paid attention to. What' more, I had tried to use "con->setSchema(schema);", but only the first letter of schema was received. I could't find the connection between your link and my problem. I am sorry.

Comment: @lcq Did you try what I said? Your `SELECT` query is currently invalid and the first letter of the invalid word is 'u'. I can't promise that it's the only problem with your code, but it is one!

Comment: I tried what you have recommended. But the error never changes.  Personally,  this sentence "stmt->execute(db);" leads to the error. In other words, 'u' is corresponding to query "use account".

Comment: @lcq How do you know it's that sentence? How do you verify that? Present your [MCVE] that can be reproduced please.

Comment: After I replaced database "user" by the database "test_user" in the sentence "SELECT * FROM `user` ", the error is still about 'u'.